# Conflicts between Microsoft STL and Stlport STL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, stl, stlport

I have installed Stlport on my windows computer, and in order to substitute Microsoft STL with Stlport in VC10, I have added the head files of Stlport to Include Directories(Property Pages->VC++ Directories->Include Directories), put `stl_port.lib` in the link (Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies  ), and `stlport.dll` in the searching directory. Moreover, I also defined the following macros: `STLP_DONT_USE_AUTO_LINK;_STLP_LEAKS_PEDANTIC;_STLP_USE_DYNAMIC_LIB` (C/C++->Preprocessor Definitions).

It seems work very well when I invoke STL functions. However, when I invoke the third-party libraries (with lib and dll) that relies on STL, I will have STL conflict problems. The reason I guess is because the third party libraries use Microsoft STL. A typical error is as follows:

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::namedWindow(class stlp_std::basic_string<char,class stlp_std::char_traits<char>,class stlp_std::allocator<char> > const &,int)" (?namedWindow@cv@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DV?$char_traits@D@stlp_std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@stlp_std@@H@Z) referenced in function _main    C:\Research\OpencvTest\OpencvTest.obj
```

I also tried to build the third party libraries from the source codes, but I have met with the similar link error:

```
grfmt_jpeg2000.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class stlp_std::allocator<char> __thiscall stlp_std::basic_string<char,class stlp_std::char_traits<char>,class stlp_std::allocator<char> >::get_allocator(void)const " (__imp_?get_allocator@?$basic_string@DV?$char_traits@D@stlp_std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@stlp_std@@QBE?AV?$allocator@D@2@XZ) referenced in function "class stlp_std::basic_string<char,class stlp_std::char_traits<char>,class stlp_std::allocator<char> > __cdecl stlp_std::operator+<char,class stlp_std::char_traits<char>,class stlp_std::allocator<char> >(char,class stlp_std::basic_string<char,class stlp_std::char_traits<char>,class stlp_std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??$?HDV?$char_traits@D@stlp_std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@stlp_std@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DV?$char_traits@D@stlp_std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@DABV10@@Z)
```

I was wondering what I can do to solve the link error problem. Thanks!

Comment: I have no solution for this, just a note that STLPort is now a rather old library (2008) and has no general advantage over the standard lib provided by VC2010. If you don't have a *very* specific requirement, this will not be that productive.

Comment: It should also be noted that the VC2010 library has quite good C++11 functionality, while for natural reasons STLPort is sorely lacking.

Comment: @BoPersson The reason why I choose STLPort is because STLPort can work well for different platforms.

Comment: @feelfree - If you write desktop or server apps for, say, Windows, Linux, and OSX, the compilers for each of those platforms all have standard libraries that are actively maintained and newer than STLPort. I would only consider it for some exotic device where the options are limited.